# How to hide slideshow's title when populating from database?

Tags: jquery, image, slideshow

I want to ask in jessore slideshow, I am populating the images and titles from database, and everything is working perfect but my only problem, why when no title in the database (or when it's NULL).

I am still getting the title bar shown with a blank value?

here is the code:

```
<?php
    $mysql_command = "CALL sp_populate_article_media(:param_article_guid)";
    $mysql_query = $mysql_connection->prepare($mysql_command);
    $mysql_query->bindParam(':param_article_guid', $_GET["aid"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $mysql_query->execute();

    $mysql_row_count = $mysql_query->rowCount();

    if ($mysql_row_count <= 0) {
?>
<img src="<?php echo $_SESSION["domain_name"]; ?>images/temp_image.png" width="720px" height="300px" />
<?php } else { ?>
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 720px; height: 300px;">
<div u="slides" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 720px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
<?php while($mysql_row = $mysql_query->fetch()) { ?>
<!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
<!-- You can move inline styles (except 'top', 'left', 'width' and 'height') to css file or css block. -->                
<!-- Slides Container -->                    
<div>
    <img u="image" src="<?php echo $_SESSION["domain_name"]; ?>gallery/members/<?php echo $_SESSION["member_guid"]; ?>/<?php echo $_SESSION["channel_guid"]; ?>/<?php echo $_GET["aid"]; ?>/<?php echo $mysql_row['file_name']; ?>.png" />
<?php if (isset($mysql_row['media_title'])) { ?>
    <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|B" style="position: absolute; top: 250px; left: 0px; width: 720px; height: 50px;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 720px; height: 50px; background-color: Black; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);"></div>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 720px; height: 50px; color: White; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 50px; text-align: center;">
            <?php echo $mysql_row['media_title']; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<!-- Slide -->
<!-- Jssor Slider End -->
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

http://www.jassimrahma.com - http://www.xoompage.com

Comment: Please add the relevant code here so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: post updated with the code.

Comment: please leave an url of your page

Comment: Thanks Guys. Problem was solved.